# Integration tests sporadically timeout on Heroku hobby-dev

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, jasmine, timeout

Since we do not get any helpful support from help.heroku.com we make the last try here.

We are developping a classic web app consisting of:

```
    -----        -----        ----
    |WEB| <----> |API| <----> |DB|
    -----        -----        ----
```

We currently are working with the following Heroku Dynos/Datastores

- Heroku Postgres: Hobby Basic
- Heroku API Dyno: Hobby
- Heroku WEB Dyno: Hobby

The tech stack is:

- runtime: nodejs (4.4.0)
- db: postgres (9.6.1)
- testframework: jasminejs (2.5.1)
- query builder: knexjs (0.10.0)

We recently moved to from self hosted docker environment to Heroku and configured the Herokus CI pipeline which works fine for unit testing - but not integration testing.
The tests sporadically fails with timeouts (in average every 3rd test of the same commit). This is not stable enough to build up CI/CD.

Here the error messages we get:

```
**************************************************
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************
1) integration test collections repository create() should return AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED if user is anonymous
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
2) integration test collections repository create() should return AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED if user is not space MEMBER
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
3) integration test collections repository create() should return collection if user is space MEMBER
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

For testing purposes we configured knex connection pooling to use one connection only:

```
export default {
    client: 'pg',
    connection: DB_URL,
    pool: {
    max: 1,
    min: 1
    }
};
```

The typical integration test setup is:

```
describe('integration test', () => {
    describe('collections repository create()', () => {
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Before the test block is execute all fixtures are loaded into the DB
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        beforeAll((callback) => {
            seed(path.join(__dirname, 'fixtures'))
            .then(callback)
            .catch((error) => {
                fail(error);
                callback();
            });
        });

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Truncate all data from the DB before the next test block gets executed
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        afterAll(resetDB);

        it('should return AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED if user is anonymous', (callback) => {
            testUtils.testAsync({
                callback,
                catchTest: (error) => {
                    expect(error).toEqual(jasmine.any(repositoryErrors.AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED));
                },
                runAsync: create({ props: { space: { id: 1 } } })
            });
        });

        it('should return AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED if user is not space MEMBER', (callback) => {
            testUtils.testAsync({
                callback,
                catchTest: (error) => {
                    expect(error).toEqual(jasmine.any(repositoryErrors.AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED));
                },
                runAsync: create({ props: { space: { id: 1 } }, userId: 1 })
            });
        });

        it('should return collection if user is space MEMBER', (callback) => {
            testUtils.testAsync({
                callback,
                runAsync: create({ props: { space: { id: 1 } }, userId: 2 }),
                thenTest: (outcome) => {
                    expect(outcome).toEqual({ id: '1' });
                }
            });
        });
    ...
```

seed:

```
const tableOrder = [
    'users',
    'guidelines',
    'collections',
    'spaces',
    'details',
    'files',
    'guidelinesAuthors',
    'collectionsUsers',
    'spacesUsers',
    'guidelinesCollections',
    'spacesCollections',
    'guidelinesDetails',
    'guidelinesFiles',
    'comments',
    'commentsReplies',
    'notifications'
];

export default function seed(path) {
    return db.raw('BEGIN;')
    .then(() => {
        return tableOrder.reduce((promise, table) => {
        return promise
            .then(() => slurp({ path, table }))
            .then(() => {
                updateIdSequence(table)
                    .catch((error) => {
                        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                        console.log(
                            `Updating id sequence for table '${table}' failed! Error: `,
                            error.message
                            );
                    });
            });
        }, Promise.resolve()).then(() => db.raw('COMMIT;'));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('SEED DATA FAILED', error);

        return db.raw('ROLLBACK;');
    });
}
...
```

resetDB:

```
export default function resetDB(callback) {
    const sql = 'BEGIN; '
    + 'SELECT truncateAllData(); '
    + 'SELECT restartSequences(); '
    + 'COMMIT;';

    return db.raw(sql)
    .then(callback)
    .catch((error) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        console.log('TRUNCATE TABLES FAILED', error);

        return db.raw('ROLLBACK;');
    });
}
```

Until now, these test have been running on local machines (Linux/Mac) and Codeship without any problem.

After almost two weeks of trying to get this work we made zero progress on this issue. I can't see anything wrong with this configuration and I start to belive Heroku has a serious issue with the datastores...

Has anybody experienced similar issues on Heroku?
Any idea what we can try else to get this work?